# reference does not exist but I'm returning a value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to filter a range for integer values, so that I can put it through the min function and find its minimum value.
My function so far:

```js
/**
 * Returns true if input is an integer, otherwise returns false
 * @param {number|Array<Array<number>>} Val or list of vals to check
 * @customfunction
 */
function INTEGERVALS(input) {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return input.filter(function(item) {
      Number.isInteger(item)
    })
  } else {
    return Number.isInteger(input) ? input : NaN
  }
  return Error
}
```

Using the custom function returns the error "reference does not exist". From what I've seen, this is because no value is being returned from the function. However, there are multiple return values, and if none of them apply, I return Error.
Putting it through arrayformula doesn't work.

I expected the function to return a column containing the integers in the range because I was only filtering a column but again, sheets threw an error.

Also, I used the input H2:H5 as the range.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be in questions. Consider adding it as a answer below in the answer box. You may also gain reputation, which will help your future questions.

Comment: A plain vanilla formula like `=filter(A2:A, isnumber(A2:A), int(A2:A) = A2:A)` would probably work better. Wrap that in `min()` to get the smallest value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that input was an array of arrays, with the subarrays each containing one object, so I put them through a filter to turn the array of subarrays into an array of objects.

Code:

```js
/**
 * Filters an array of numbers by removing all non-integers.
 * @param {number|Array<Array<number>>} Val or list of vals to check
 * @customfunction
 */
function INTEGERVALS(input) {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return input.map(([x]) => (x)).filter(function(item) {
      return Number.isInteger(item)
    })
  } else {
    return Number.isInteger(input) ? input : NaN
  }
}
```